# Design Pattern for Server and Client Objects in Unity Netcode

Tags: unity, c#, networking

I'm struggling with how to solve the general problem of having a server-side GameObject which does most of the work and a client side object that's coupled with it for UI purposes only.

As an example, on the server side, I have a navmesh agent with a bunch of components like colliders for triggering events. On the client side, I only want to include parts of the GameObject that are needed for visual rendering.

I don't want to make the whole thing a NetworkObject, as it would carry over all extra server-side components. But I also need the transform on the client side synced with the server side.

One solution might be creating both and then removing all unecessary components on the client side after spawning. But wondering if there's a cleaner way.

Comment: Not an identical issue, but you may find some useful tips in this other [Q&A thread about maintaining separate behaviour for client-side and headless server versions of objects](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/185824/39518).

Comment: That was somewhat helpful, thanks